# python,pandas do group wise value_count()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a    b
1    2
1    3
2    4
2    4
3    3
```

I want to group by 'a' and for every group I want to do values_count() of 'b'.
What I want to get is something like:

```
for a = 1: b[2:1,3:1]
for a = 2: b[4:2]
for a = 3: b[3:1]
```

is there any one liner for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df

 Out[20]: 
    a  b
 0  1  2
 1  1  3
 2  2  4
 3  2  4
 4  3  3

df.groupby(['a']).apply(lambda group: group.b.value_counts())

 Out[21]: 
 a   
 1  3    1
    2    1
 2  4    2
 3  3    1
 dtype: int64
```